# When can baby-step giant-step algorithm not be used to solve a DLP?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying to understand when there is a solution to the general DLP: given `a`, `b`, and `n` find `x` such that `a^x == b (mod n)`. General in the sense that `n` can be any positive integer.

One algorithm is the baby-step giant-step algorithm. However this requires the calculation of `a^-m` which does not always exist.

My questions are:

1. Under what conditions on `a`, `b` and `n` can BSGS be used?
2. Are there sub-linear time algorithms that solve DLP under more general conditions?

Comment: I take it the problem is, given $a,b,n$, find $x$ such that $a^x\equiv b\bmod n$. It's not clear whether you are asking how to know whether there is a solution, or whether you think there is always a solution and you want an algorithm for finding it. Well, there isn't always a solution. For example, $2^x\equiv3\bmod7$ has no solution. There is an algorithm to decide whether it has a solution; just try $x=1,2,3,\dots$ until you find one that works or you get to $x=n-1$ without finding one. Efficient algorithms, that's a different question, about which one could write a whole book.

Comment: And that book would involve ideas way beyond "the more basic concepts in Number Theory".

Comment: I'm interested under what conditions the BSGS algorithm can be used. And I'm thinking of algorithms typically more efficient than brute forcing `x` which would be `O(n)`

Comment: It's not clear to me that there are any situations in which BSGS *can't* be used. Do you know of any?

Comment: Shanks algorithm requires the calculation of a^-m which does not necessary exist - so that’s on situation right?

Comment: I suppose in that case you could write $n=rs$ with $\gcd(a,s)=1$ and then solve $a^x\equiv b\bmod s$ by BSGS, and combine it with $a^x\equiv b\bmod r$ which should be easier to solve.

Comment: MathJax is your friend, OP

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean by combine it?

Comment: If you can get a solution modulo $s$, and a solution modulo $r$, some form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem should get you a solution modulo $rs$.